# Firefox prints only first page and cuts the page on the right

Tags: css, firefox, printing, overflow

I had big trouble with printing from Firefox (any version, mine is 16.0.2, but even Aurora dev builds did the same). 
When printing the page, Shrink to fit in the Print preview doesn't work. Only way, how to fit the page onto the paper is selecting Zoom 70% in the same dialog.
Other problem:
it prints only first page.
What to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I needed to adapt the CSS file for printing, so I've done one. It works flawlessly anywhere, but not in Firefox. What was the problem?

First I've tried specifying Width and height for BODY and HTML in the print.css file. Than margins, etc.

Later I figured out what was the problem:
standard CSS file had the following in it:

```
body {
 ...
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

So I've added the following into the print.css file:

```
body {
 overflow-x: visible;
 overflow-y: visible;
}
```

I guess, if you had only overflow specified in the CSS, not -x & -y, you would need to specify only overflow:visible in the print.css file.

Printing from Firefox works now as it should. I just thought, that this may help somebody, who has strange printing behavior happening in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Kokesh's answer, some times attribute

```
display: table
```

generates this problem too. So you need change it to 'block' or another that fits to your requeriments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the fixes suggested in other answers but they didn't solve the problem for me. After a lot of research and trial & error, I have found [this article](https://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint) by A list apart. I was skeptical because it's so old but it states that:

> If a floated element runs past the bottom of a printed page, the rest of the float will effectively disappear, as it won’t be printed on the next page.

As I have a big floated container I thought I'd give it a try. So, I made a mix from the other answers and this article and came up with this:

```
body { 
    overflow: visible !important; 
    overflow-x: visible !important; 
    overflow-y: visible !important; 
}

/*this is because I use angular and have this particular layout*/
body > .fade-ng-cloak { 
    height: 100%; 
    display: block;
    flex: none;
    float: none;
}
.l-content,
.l-sidebar {
    float: none;
}
```

So basically:

1. Setting body to `overflow: visible`
2. Setting elements that behave as wrappers to `display: block`, eliminate all `flex` styles and reset height if necessary
3. Eliminate `float` on long containers

That mix worked for me! I'm so happy I thought I'd share :)